# Hello World project build with a dependency error

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.2

Has anyone met this problem before?

When I build a HelloWorld example, I get the following error:

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
>   > Module version MyApplication:app:unspecified, configuration '_debugApkCopy' declares a dependency on configuration 'default' which is not declared in the module descriptor for MyApplication:app:unspecified

the following is my build.grade file :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven{url "https://jitpack.io"}
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```